# Duplicate values when clicking back button - FIXED

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Here is my situation.

In this screen, I click the comments button.

[image]

The Comment activity opens and I type what I want.

[image]

The comment is added successfully in firebase and it takes me back in detail activity.

[image]

So far everything is great! Now let's add another comment. Now you see I get duplicate comments.

[image]

I hope you see that too. Now in the **DetailActivity** I have a method called `queryFirebaseDb()` and that method is called inside both `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods. If I don't use the onResume() method the data will not be display after clicking the back button from the CommentActivity. You see where I am going now right? The question is how to avoid duplicate data after coming back from CommentActivity. Here is my code.

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Comment> commentArrayList;

ImageView mImageView;
TextView mTitle;
TextView mDate;
TextView mDescription;
TextView mAuthor;
ToggleButton mFavBtn;
private TextView noCommentsTextView;
private TextView commentsTextView;

private ImageButton imageButton;

private FloatingActionButton mShareBtn;

private String newsTitle;
private String newsImage;
private String newsDate;
private String newsDescription;
private static String NEWS_SHARE_HASHTAG = "#EasyNewsApp";
private String date1;
private String date2;
private String newsUrl;
private String newsAuthor;

private Cursor favoriteCursor;

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

private static Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

private Uri uri;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private DisplayCommentsAdapter displayCommentsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    mAuthor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_author);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_image_view);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_title);
    mDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_publish_date);
    mDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_description);
    noCommentsTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noCommentsTextView);
    commentsTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commentsTextView);
    mShareBtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.share_floating_btn);
    mFavBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.fav_news_btn);
    imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.detail_comment_image_btn);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_comments);

    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));

    commentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    mFavBtn.setTextOn(null);
    mFavBtn.setText(null);
    mFavBtn.setTextOff(null);

    newsAuthor = i.getStringExtra("author");
    newsImage = i.getStringExtra("image");
    newsTitle = i.getStringExtra("newsTitle");
    newsDate = i.getStringExtra("date");
    newsDescription = i.getStringExtra("description");
    newsUrl = i.getStringExtra("url");




        date1 = newsDate.substring(0, 10);
        date2 = newsDate.substring(11, 19);

    Picasso.with(this).load(newsImage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
            .into(mImageView);

    mTitle.setText(newsTitle);
    mAuthor.setText("Author: " + newsAuthor);
    mDescription.setText(newsDescription);
    mDate.setText(date2 + ", " + date1);

    mShareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent shareIntent = createShareNewsIntent();
            startActivity(shareIntent);
        }
    });
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent commentIntent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, CommentActivity.class);
            commentIntent.putExtra("newsTitle",newsTitle);
            startActivity(commentIntent);
        }
    });

    /**
     * Handling the add/remove news part. We check if the specific news article
     * exists in favourite.db.
     */
    favoriteCursor = getContentResolver().query(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_TITLE + "=?",
            new String[]{newsTitle},
            null);

    /**
     * If yes then set the toggle button to true
     */
    if (favoriteCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        try {
            mFavBtn.setChecked(true);
        } finally {
            favoriteCursor.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Else click the toggle button to add the news article as favourite
     */
    mFavBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, final boolean isChecked) {
            /**
             * If checked the add the news article as favourite.
             */
            if (isChecked) {
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                        contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_TITLE, newsTitle);
                        contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_AUTHOR, newsAuthor);
                        contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_DESCRIPTION, newsDescription);
                        contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_URL, newsUrl);
                        contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_URL_TO_IMAGE, newsImage);
                        contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_PUBLISHED_AT, newsDate);

                        //The actual insertion in the db.
                        uri = getContentResolver().insert(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                        Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Article with title:  " + newsTitle + " was added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }.execute();
            } else {
                /**
                 * If you uncheck the toggle button then delete the news article from the favourite db.
                 */
                Uri newsTitleOfFavNews = FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.buildNewsUriWithTitle(newsTitle);
                //String title = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);// Get the task ID from the URI path

                getContentResolver().delete(
                        newsTitleOfFavNews,
                        null,
                        null);
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "News article deleted from favourites ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });


    queryFirebaseDb();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

   if(item.getItemId() == R.id.detail_browser_btn){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newsUrl));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    } if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}

private Intent createShareNewsIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setText(NEWS_SHARE_HASHTAG + "\n\n\n" + newsTitle
                    + "\n\n\n" + newsDescription
                    + "\n\n\n" + newsDate)
            .getIntent();

    return shareIntent;
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //queryFirebaseDb();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    queryFirebaseDb();
    //displayCommentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void queryFirebaseDb(){

    /**
     * Querying the database to check if the specific article has comments.
     */

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = mDatabase.child("comments").orderByChild("newsTitle").equalTo(newsTitle);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshots : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Comment comment = dataSnapshots.getValue(Comment.class);

                    //mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

                    commentArrayList.add(comment);

                    displayCommentsAdapter = new DisplayCommentsAdapter(this,commentArrayList);

                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(displayCommentsAdapter);

                    displayCommentsAdapter.setCommentsData(commentArrayList);

                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(commentArrayList.size()));

                }
                noCommentsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //commentsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else{
                //Toast.makeText(DisplayComments.this,"There are no comments posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                noCommentsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
/*
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState", mFavBtn.isChecked());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFavBtn.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState",false));
}
*/
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mFavBtn.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState",false));
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("newsList",commentArrayList);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState",mFavBtn.isChecked());
    outState.getParcelableArrayList("newsList");

  }
 }
```

and

```
public class CommentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String REQUIRED = "Required";
private static final String TAG = CommentActivity.class.getSimpleName();

Toolbar toolbar;

DatabaseReference mDatabase;
EditText titleEt;
EditText bodyEt;
Button commentBtn;
String newsTitle;
Intent i;
String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.comment_toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add comment");

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    titleEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_title);
    bodyEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_body);
    commentBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);

    i = getIntent();

    newsTitle = i.getStringExtra("newsTitle");




    commentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            submitPost();
        }
    });

}

private void submitPost() {
    final String title = titleEt.getText().toString();
    final String body = bodyEt.getText().toString();

    // Title is required
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
        titleEt.setError(REQUIRED);
        return;
    }

    // Body is required
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(body)) {
        bodyEt.setError(REQUIRED);
        return;
    }

    // Disable button so there are no multi-posts
    setEditingEnabled(false);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Posting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // [START single_value_read]
    final String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();


    mDatabase.child("Users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Get user value
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);


                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    if (user == null) {
                        // User is null, error out
                        Log.e(TAG, "User " + userId + " is unexpectedly null");
                        Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this,
                                "Error: could not fetch user.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Write new post
                        name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                        String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

                        writeNewPost(userId,strDate,name,newsTitle, title, body);
                    }

                    // Finish this Activity, back to the stream
                    setEditingEnabled(true);
                    finish();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    setEditingEnabled(true);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
    // [END single_value_read]
}

 private void writeNewPost(String userId,String date,String 
 commentAuthor, String newsTitle, String commentTitle, String 
 commentBody){
   String key = mDatabase.child("comments").push().getKey();
   Comment comment = new Comment(userId, date, 
   commentAuthor,newsTitle,commentTitle,commentBody);
   Map<String, Object> commentValues = comment.toMap();

   Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
   childUpdates.put("/comments/" + key, commentValues);

   mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
   }

private void setEditingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    titleEt.setEnabled(enabled);
    bodyEt.setEnabled(enabled);
    if (enabled) {
        commentBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        commentBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  } 
}
```

**UPDATE**

I used this

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    finish();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

and voila!

Comment: Does your database have same record twice or it just show in the ui ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some stuff I thought you would know when doing Android:**

Basically, in android, you need to understand how the life cycle works. So, when you call `queryFirebaseDb()` from `onCreate` and from `onResume`, your app is doing two queries at the same time when activity starts initially.

Lifecycle is like this `OnCreate -> onResume`. So, it makes sense that when activity starts, query gets executed once on `onCreate` than on `onResume` based on your logic.

**Answer is here**

I noticed that you are using `ArrayList<Comment> commentArrayList;`, which is an `ArrayList` structure, which lets you have duplicate data. And, if you look into the behavior of `Firebase` and how your query is structured, it is like this,

```
Query query = mDatabase.child("comments").orderByChild("newsTitle").equalTo(newsTitle);
```

This query means that you are **taking all the comments, the previous comment and the new comment, (not just new comment),** which I think you either just want (1) to get recently added comment or (2) to replace the old comments with new one.

The first way of doing this sounds complicated to me, though that is not impossible. But, second way of doing is rather easy.

Therefore, to solve this, 
simply, replace the arrayList you have with this data.

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            ArrayList<Comment> tempComments = new ArrayList();

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshots : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Comment comment = dataSnapshots.getValue(Comment.class);

                //mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

                tempComments.add(comment);

                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(commentArrayList.size()));

            }

            commentArrayList = tempComments; //assuming you want to store the data in the class fields 
            displayCommentsAdapter = new DisplayCommentsAdapter(this,commentArrayList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(displayCommentsAdapter);
            displayCommentsAdapter.setCommentsData(commentArrayList);

            noCommentsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //commentsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
```